# CSS for table is not working in outlook 2016

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to send an email using my python code. which generates the following html and send using python.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
    <table>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>
    <tr><td>x</td><td>y</td><td>z</td></tr>
    <tr><td>p</td><td>q</td><td>r</td></tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This shows really nice table in browser.. However in outlook I don't see style sheet applied for table.

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you to set it inline

Comment: @MaxiGui there are certain things I can't set inline.. like alternate style for row

Comment: Why not ? I guess you are doing a loop, so just set a count and check if count is even or odd ?